# REPL for Logo programming language

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, logo-lang

Is there any free Logo implementation that offers classic stdin/stdout [repl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) environment under Windows? Like python and ghci are.

As far as I can tell FMSLogo is GUI only and ucblogo is terminal based without ability for external program to capture its output.

The reason I ask the question is that I would like to setup a minimal Logo development environment around SublimeText editor and its SublimeREPL plugin. I have already implemented (some) syntax highlighting, auto-completions and inline help. See [here](https://github.com/glaukon-ariston/Logo/tree/master/SublimeText).

I would be interested in hearing others talk about their Logo programming set up.

Answer (score 0):

FMSLogo is GUI but it does have command line options that allows it to load a file to interpret. As far as I know it does not allow to read files from stdin. From the help:

```
-L
-L file1 [file2]
```

> FMSLogo allows you to LOAD one or more filenames on the command line
>   when starting FMSLogo. These files are loaded before the interpreter
>   starts reading commands from the commander. If you load a file that
>   runs a program that includes a BYE instruction, FMSLogo runs that
>   program and exits. You can therefore write stand-alone programs in
>   FMSLogo and run them as new shortcuts. Note, the "-L" switch must
>   follow any other switches.
>
> Example:

```
fmslogo.exe -L myprog.lgo
```

> I would be interested in hearing others talk about their Logo programming set up.

I use Vim which does have syntax highlighting, and FMSLogo. And have this in my logolib folder:

```
to CG [:file "%%%] 0
ifelse :file = "%%% [
 if not namep "load.file: [make "load.file: "script.lgo]
 load :load.file:
] [
 make "load.file: :file
 bury [[] [load.file:]]
 load :file
]
end

bury "cg
```

I have both applications open at the same time. I add code to the Vim session and save the logo file.

In FMSLogo I initially write

```
(cg "myfile.lgo)
```

and later I simply reload with CG

Some times I write:

```
GC MainProcedureName
```

and reuse that line by pressing UP arrow, UP arrow, ENTER in the FMSLogo Command Center

If the name of the file is script.lgo, I don't even need to say

```
(cg "script.lgo)
```